# How can I auto install missing perl modules when running a script?

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

I am looking for a way to auto install a missing perl module when my script runs. I would like to use cpan plus since it "seems" to available on both Windows and Linux but maybe I could have a way to drop down to standard cpan if cpan plus is not installed.

So how could one go about this? There is of course the cpan plus / cpan modules but are those able to integrated into a script?

Comment: duplicates [automatically install missing modules from CPAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183293/automatically-install-missing-modules-from-cpan); related [Distributing a Perl Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385759/distributing-a-perl-application). – I will give a [talk about this very topic at YAPC::EU](http://act.yapc.eu/ye2012/talk/4065).

Answer (score 0):

Check this module: Carton [Carton in CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/carton-v0.9.4/lib/Carton.pod), so first you installed all modules for your script, then you will make special dependency file under Carton and as result using this special file in other PC to install all dependency for you script. Please read description of this module in CPAN.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Interesting...., I think that would work but I was looking for something more inpedendent, something more based on core modules that would allow almost anyone to run the modules and have everything contruct without the need for installing a prerequisite. Before installing the dependancies. Follow me?